# Parse Multi-Part Email with Sub-parts using Python

Tags: python

I am using this function to parse an email.  I am able to parse "simple" multi-part emails, but it produces an error (UnboundLocalError: local variable 'html' referenced before assignment) when the email defines multiple boundaries (sub-parts).  I would like the script to separate the text and html portions and return only the html portion (unless there is no html portion, return the text).

```
def get_text(msg):
text = ""
if msg.is_multipart():
    for part in msg.get_payload():
        if part.get_content_charset() is None:
            charset = chardet.detect(str(part))['encoding']
        else:
            charset = part.get_content_charset()
        if part.get_content_type() == 'text/plain':
            text = unicode(part.get_payload(decode=True),str(charset),"ignore").encode('utf8','replace')
        if part.get_content_type() == 'text/html':
            html = unicode(part.get_payload(decode=True),str(charset),"ignore").encode('utf8','replace')
    if html is None:
        return text.strip()
    else:
        return html.strip()
else:
    text = unicode(msg.get_payload(decode=True),msg.get_content_charset(),'ignore').encode('utf8','replace')
    return text.strip()
```

Comment: You seem to have omitted some useful information: what is the error message and what is the mail handling library.
Also, you always check the variable called html but only declare it when there is a text/html part.

Comment: I added the error message to the post.  The mail handling library is simply "email".  The html variable is only used in this function.  Any idea why the error could be occurring?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Like the comment said you always check html but only declare it in one of the specific cases.  Thats what the error is telling you, you reference html before assigning it.  In python it is not valid to check if something is None if it hasn't been assigned to anything.  For example open the python interactive prompt:

```
>>> if y is None:
...   print 'none'
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'y' is not defined
```

As you can see you cannot merely check for none to see if a variable exists.  Back to your specific case.

You need to initially set html to None, and then later you will be checking if it is still None.  i.e. edit your code like this:

```
def get_text(msg):
text = ""
if msg.is_multipart():
    html = None
    for part in msg.get_payload():
        if part.get_content_charset() is None:
            charset = chardet.detect(str(part))['encoding']
        else:
            charset = part.get_content_charset()
        if part.get_content_type() == 'text/plain':
            text = unicode(part.get_payload(decode=True),str(charset),"ignore").encode('utf8','replace')
        if part.get_content_type() == 'text/html':
            html = unicode(part.get_payload(decode=True),str(charset),"ignore").encode('utf8','replace')
    if html is None:
        return text.strip()
    else:
        return html.strip()
else:
    text = unicode(msg.get_payload(decode=True),msg.get_content_charset(),'ignore').encode('utf8','replace')
    return text.strip()
```

This explains a little more:
http://code.activestate.com/recipes/59892-testing-if-a-variable-is-defined/

Comment: This code was useful. Only change I had to make was to supports parts of type 'multipart/alternative' - you have to do the same loop for the subparts of that part.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the same code with OlliM's helpful suggestion.  Without this change you can't properly parse "multipart/alternative" containers in emails.

```
import chardet

def get_text(msg):
    """ Parses email message text, given message object
    This doesn't support infinite recursive parts, but mail is usually not so naughty.
    """
    text = ""
    if msg.is_multipart():
        html = None
        for part in msg.get_payload():
            if part.get_content_charset() is None:
                charset = chardet.detect(str(part))['encoding']
            else:
                charset = part.get_content_charset()
            if part.get_content_type() == 'text/plain':
                text = unicode(part.get_payload(decode=True),str(charset),"ignore").encode('utf8','replace')
            if part.get_content_type() == 'text/html':
                html = unicode(part.get_payload(decode=True),str(charset),"ignore").encode('utf8','replace')
            if part.get_content_type() == 'multipart/alternative':
                for subpart in part.get_payload():
                    if subpart.get_content_charset() is None:
                        charset = chardet.detect(str(subpart))['encoding']
                    else:
                        charset = subpart.get_content_charset()
                    if subpart.get_content_type() == 'text/plain':
                        text = unicode(subpart.get_payload(decode=True),str(charset),"ignore").encode('utf8','replace')
                    if subpart.get_content_type() == 'text/html':
                        html = unicode(subpart.get_payload(decode=True),str(charset),"ignore").encode('utf8','replace')

        if html is None:
            return text.strip()
        else:
            return html.strip()
    else:
        text = unicode(msg.get_payload(decode=True),msg.get_content_charset(),'ignore').encode('utf8','replace')
        return text.strip()
```

Writing more elegant structure that doesn't repeat any code is left as an exercise to the reader.

Also, check out this [helpful diagram of container structure](http://blog.magiksys.net/parsing-email-using-python-content).

Answer (score 0):

Following changes were required in my code: **unicode** to be changed to **str** and **str(part)** to be changed to **bytes(part)** in charset = chardet.detect(**str**(part))['encoding']. I applied bs4 to html. Code was useful for my project. Thanks.